# My firewall icon doesnt work.....I have tried setting up the JAVA path but for some reason, it doesnt work

Tags: cmd, scripting

I set my path to JAVA bin. The system doesn't recognize it for some reason and cant seem to find the administrator for sometime.

What I do as a work around I go to command prompt and type the following commands:

set PATH=%PATH%;c:\amir\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

cd c:\myutilities\auth

java - jar auth.jar

I was wondering if there is another work around where I don't have to type all that again....? (perhaps create a command that I run that does all of the above)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` may contain spaces. First, properly quote it. And, you might have another jdk earlier in the PATH (so set it *first*). Something like

```
set "PATH=c:\amir\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%PATH%"
```

Then, you don't need want a space between `-` and `jar`. So, use something like

```
cd c:\myutilities\auth
java -jar auth.jar
```

Finally, you should be able to copy and paste into your command prompt (or just save the above as a bat script).

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "PATH=c:\amir\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%PATH%"
java -jar c:\myutilities\auth\auth.jar
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks...Created a bat file (amir.bat) and working now!